# How to disable the Function keys of the Magic Keyboard as it was before in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, windows-registry, boot-camp

How to disable Function keys of the Magic Keyboard as it was before in Windows 10?

I thought it would be more convenient if I Apple Magic Keyboard (A1644) works like the symbols printed on each Function key, and I found the following link.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UfTTv9AQOSw&ab_channel=MacKooper-Hey%2CI%27mCurious%21

I installed the program called "MagicMac". The program contains several batch files and the files downloaded files such as bootcamp.msi and installed drivers of Magic Mouse and Magic Keyboard if I correctly understood.

At first, I liked it, but then I wanted to go back to the original because some of the shortcut keys related to Functions keys (F1 & F2, F7 ~ F12) I had been using were no longer working in some of the programs.

So I checked the comments of the Youtube Video and tried uninstalling bootcamp.msi as advised by the video uploader. However, after restarting the computer nothing changed and the Brightness and Volume control keys still work.

I tried

- uninstalling devices even hidden devices related to Magic Keyboard in Device Manager, and updated drivers by browsing for drivers and selecting the same driver from the list of available drivers,
- using troubleshooting tool in windows,
- installed bootcamp.msi again, then uninstalled it again in both normal and sade mode,
- using "system restore" (it always failed while deleting file/directory related to iCloud in both normaland safe mode)
- deleting "Boot Camp Services" program via WMIC https://github.com/timsutton/brigadier/issues/20
  but none of them worked.

While looking for other solutions, I found some addresses with the name "KeymapFn" in Registry Editor. Apparently, that binary data has something to do with the Function keys.

The contents of the data in the following address are down below.

- Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\KeyMagic2
- Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\KeyMagic2

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcOTD.png

- Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\DriverDatabase\DriverPackages\keymagic2.inf_amd64_d84dc2dd929fae11\Configurations\Dri_BTH_Inst.NT\Services\KeyMagic2
- Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\DriverDatabase\DriverPackages\keymagic2.inf_amd64_d84dc2dd929fae11\Configurations\Dri_HID_Inst.NT\Services\KeyMagic2

https://i.stack.imgur.com/amNtu.png

Is it okay to delete some binary data in the Registry Editor?

I changed the value of "enable" in the first 2 addresses from "01" to "00", and restarted the computer but still function keys worked. I also tried changing the "enable" value from "01" to "00" in both normal and safe mode, but I got a pop-up error message saying "Cannot edit enable: Error writing the value's new contents."

Do the newly assigned function keys remain the same because the registry values remain the same even after uninstalling bootcamp.msi several times? Would deleting all the data in the registry restore it if so?